# Two threads and two CPU

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some struggle  to understand the following situation:
(i am working in java)
Let's say, we have an object o , two different threads t1 and t2 and two CPU.
if t1  calls o.method1 and t2 calls the o.method2 at the same time, can cpu1 run o.method1 and cpu2 o.method2 at the same time?

Comment: Yes. If they are not synchronized, it can happen at same time. For extra confusion, even if you have only one CPU, it could happen at same time with two threads (one thread getting preempted while inside a method1 and then second thread entering method2).

Comment: they can, whether it's safe it's completely different story

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it *can*. However, nothing *guarantees* you that different threads are actually executed in *parallel*. You only have a guarantee that they are executed *concurrently*.

The operating system is free to bind your threads to one CPU (and even switch the CPUs of threads).
This is done all the time.

In particular, when other applications are running CPU-intensive computations, your two threads may share the same CPU.
In this case, your threads run *interleaved*.

(In this answer, what I said about *CPU* also applies to *CPU cores*.)

Of course, locks and synchronization can make one thread wait on the other. Still technically, this waiting can be interpreted as running, although it is not consuming CPU time.

Also note that executing methods in parallel (*usually*) has nothing to do on *which objects* you call methods. In your example, you are calling two different methods on the same object. However, this is completely irrelevant.
*Except* if both methods are markes as `synchronized` in Java, which introduces a synchronization (see paragraph above) *on this particular* object and make one thread wait until the other has finished its call on that method.

Comment: Assume that there are only two threads t1 and t2 and( no another process or threads)  in the OS System . Do both Threads run parallel now?

Comment: *If* there are also no kernel threads *and if* there are absolutely no other applications / threads, *and if* the user also did not bound a specific CPU to your threads (which he can do, but you may also programmatically change that), then yes, that's what all sane scheduling algorithms will do. In most practical cases, you will be happy. Why don't you try it out yourself?

Comment: i was just wondering, if  at one object o two methods can be run parallel through two threads and cpus. Thanks to you, it is clear that this is possible.

Comment: So i guess, even if the two threads run the same method parallel on the one object, it would be fine?

Comment: Yes, that's completely fine. Methods are just instructions for CPUs. If you have two CPUs, both can act on these instructions. Imagine you give two humans the same sheet of paper with instructions, they can still both do in parallel what is written on that paper (e.g. walk straight, turn left, walk straight, stop), as long as there are no shared resources (e.g. burn this sheet of paper). For more, you should definitely just try some code, read resources, try more code - play! And then ask *specific* programming questions here. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped :)